# visual basic display character from a string on each iteration

Tags: vb.net

i have a text file which contains the following:

> 12 13 32 41 ; 321 433 412 234 ; ...

I am trying to read the numbers and display each of them on label before i add them. I am adding each set of numbers before the ";" . the ouput should be :

> 12+13+32+41=98.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim L As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim c As Char
    Dim res As String
    Dim file As String

    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    path = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    File = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(path)
    L = File.Length
    For i = 1 To L Step 1
        c = Mid(Options.File, i)
        If c <> " " Then
            res = res & c
        Else
            Label1.Text = res
                 ' messagebox.show(res)   
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)

            res = ""
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

My problem is only the last number on the file is displayed. I didn't post the addition part.

Please help I am new to visual basic

Comment: This is VB.Net not VBA.

Comment: So, which output do you expect for the above example?

Comment: 12 13 32 41 display each number at a time for 1 second.

Comment: It works when I dislpayed the "res" on a messagebox.

Comment: Did you need to do it character by character as a learning exercise, or are you just unaware that there are easier alternatives?  When you are reading a specific character, you should use `File.SubString` instead of `Mid`.  `Mid` is a throw-back to VB6 and is discouraged in new .NET code.  Also, even if you are looping by character, a `For Each c As Char In File` loop would be easier too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Thread.Sleep(100)` is wrong for a 1 sec delay.  Sleep is in milliseconds, so you need 1000 for 1 second.

The other problem is that when you put your thread to sleep, your form is not going to repaint.    Try

```
Label1.Text = res
Label1.Refresh  
' or maybe Label1.Update
Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
```

Both `Refresh` and `Update` tell the control to repaint itself, but that really just puts a paint message in the queue, it still might not process the msg before you put the thread to sleep.

Another way is to use a Timer to measure off 1 sec of time.

Comment: I don't think Refresh will work without Application.DoEvents(). Better be using `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` from another thread.

Comment: Thank you very much Plutonix label.update did work. Appreciate all the help.

Comment: @Neo, yes it will depend on what all else is going on, but I was saving DoEvents as a last resort.

Comment: @Tash: If Plutonix's answer was helpful, please consider accepting and/or upvoting it.

Comment: I tried but since I am new to the forum it's not letting me vote

Comment: Since you asked the question, it will let you accept an answer (select the checkmark)  and move this question off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1):

As you want the updates to happen slowly, you can rely on the normal message queue of the window to update the display. You can use a timer to change what is displayed. Using Thread.Sleep() is a bad idea because it makes the UI unresponsive. This code allows for more than one Control to be updated at the same time:

```
Class TextRevealer
Property target As Control
Property text As String

Private nChars As Integer
Private tim As Timer

Sub New(target As Control, text As String)
    Me.target = target
    Me.text = text
    nChars = 1
    tim = New Timer
    tim.Interval = 100
    AddHandler tim.Tick, AddressOf RevealText
End Sub

Sub Start()
    If tim IsNot Nothing Then
        tim.Start()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub RevealText(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    target.Text = text.Substring(0, nChars)
    nChars += 1
    If nChars = text.Length Then
        tim.Stop()
        tim.Dispose()
    End If
End Sub
End Class

 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Clic
    Dim txt = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\temp\crop.txt")
    Dim txtRvlr = New TextRevealer(Label1, txt)
    txtRvlr.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim txt = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\temp\dives.txt")
    Dim txtRvlr = New TextRevealer(Label2, txt)
    txtRvlr.Start()

End Sub
```